# Meaning of - "Business leader" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Most **business leaders** recognise the link between deficit reduction and growth.

—Times, Sunday Times

What's the meaning of **business leader** here?

Comment: The people who run commercial companies.

Comment: @WeatherVane how I Will understand it using dictionary?

Comment: By googling: for example [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/business%20leader) has *a very wealthy or powerful businessman*.

Comment: @WeatherVane I interpreted it as:— **Persons that are more successful in business than other persons..**

Comment: Well, yes - because if you are successful in business you are likely to run your own company and be wealthy!

Answer (score 2):

There are two (very similar) possible interpretations.

1. It makes more sense if you rephrase "business leaders" as "those who lead business". A "business leader", therefore, is one who leads the trade of business. In other words, the sentence is saying that most successful businessmen usually display the mentioned qualities.
2. It makes more sense if you rephrase "business leaders" as "those who lead businesses". (Notice the subtle difference, plural vs. singular). A "business leader", therefore, is one who leads a business. In other words, the sentence is saying that people who run companies usually display the mentioned qualities.

The ambiguity mostly arises from the fact that "business" can be used in reference to both the general trade of business, and the concept of a business, as a noun.

The Oxford Dictionary demonstrates this very nicely. When searched on Google, it provides multiple definitions, including the conflicting:

1. "The practice of making one's living by engaging in commerce."

and

2. "A commercial operation or company."

Comment: I interpreted it as:— **Persons that are more successful in business than other persons..**